# PUT Method payload for REST Webservice

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest

I have object as

```
{
    "sch": {
        "name":"ABC",
        "time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
        ....
    }
}
```

I am trying to create payload for PUT method of REST web-service using javascript. I have created payload as:

```
var body={"sch.name":"CAD"};
```

but i am not able to update the name with new value `CAD` .

Am i doing this correctly for the "name" element?

Comment: Is it possible to shed more detail? can you place your put request code? which framework?

Comment: Hi This is the one of PUT REST method,                                                                                                             var rMsg = new RESTMessage('REST_API', 'put');
 rMsg.setRestEndPoint(url);
 var json = new JSON();
 var bodyJSON = json.encode(body);
 rMsg.setXMLParameter('payload', bodyJSON);
 var response = rMsg.execute();

Comment: What is the name of input parameter in your web service put method?

Comment: "body" is the one i am using as payload to store property and its value to modify at target.

Comment: could you show us the web method code ??

Comment: Hi This is the one of PUT REST method, var rMsg = new RESTMessage('REST_API', 'put'); rMsg.setRestEndPoint(url); var json = new JSON(); var bodyJSON = json.encode(body); rMsg.setXMLParameter('payload', bodyJSON); var response = rMsg.execute();

Comment: try putting this in the variable body - {"sch": {"name":"CAD"}};